# Upgrading a Grails app from 1.3.7 to 2.4.1

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to make a huge leap without re-learning Grails. I have a web site that I'm trying to upgrade from Grails 1.3.7 to Grails 2.4.1.

Interestingly once I set the Grails version to 2.4.1 the following happened,

```
| Installed plugin database-migration-1.4.0.....
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [jquery-1.6.1.1]. Do you want to upgrade to [jquery-1.11.1]? [y,n] y
| Installed plugin jquery-1.11.1.....
> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [tomcat-1.3.7]. Do you want to upgrade to [tomcat-7.0.54]? [y,n] y
| Uninstalled plugin [yui]
| Uninstalled plugin [spring-security-core]
| Uninstalled plugin [searchable]
| Uninstalled plugin [rendering]
| Uninstalled plugin [recaptcha]
| Uninstalled plugin [quartz]
| Uninstalled plugin [mail]
| Uninstalled plugin [jquery-ui]
| Uninstalled plugin [hibernate]
| Uninstalled plugin [google-analytics]| Uninstalled plugin [famfamfam]
| Uninstalled plugin [email-confirmation]
| Uninstalled plugin [cloud-foundry]
| Compiling 131 source files
```

A whole host of plugins were uninstalled. Digging around revealed a new set of BuildConfig plugin parameters. I naively added the core Spring security plugin as follows,

```
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.1"
    compile ':cache:1.1.6'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-SNAPSHOT"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.7.4"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```

It appears the plugin installed as I now see the following prompt:

```
*******************************************************
* You've installed the Spring Security Core plugin.   *
*                                                     *
* Next run the "s2-quickstart" script to initialize   *
* Spring Security and create your domain classes.     *
*                                                     *
*******************************************************
```

However, I still see the following compilation errors:

```
| Compiling 47 source files
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc]     /Users/myusername/Development/protocols/src/groovy/com/mycompany/web/protocols/UserProfileDetails.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser
  [groovyc]  @ line 3, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] /Users/myusername/Development/protocols/src/groovy/com/mycompany/web/protocols/UserProfileUtils.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class         org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService
  [groovyc]  @ line 3, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService
  [groovyc]    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] /Users/myusername/Development/protocols/grails-app/controllers/LoginController.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
  [groovyc]  @ line 5, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
  [groovyc]    ^
```

I've been through the release notes for Grails 2.0 and later but I'm still looking for the exact point at which I should start learning how to unravel upgrading my app's plugins.

Comment: Why did you pick that version of the Spring Security Core?  The latest version is: compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"

Comment: The 'list-plugins' command produced a bewildering array of spring security plugins, which includes the plugin I used: 'spring-security-core<2.0-SNAPSHOT>   --  Spring Security Core Plugin'

Comment: .deleted this comment.

Comment: Looks like that upgrade overwrote you BuildConfig.groovy. Do you have any VCS? Please compare the old and the new versions of that config. And yes, people are correctly said that spring-security must be updated to RC3. Some classes are deprecated in Grails 2.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like I was overthinking this. It now appears to be as simple as a namespace change. The spring security core plugin classes are no longer have package names prefaced,

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity
```

they have moved to a new root package name,

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity
```